# No value associated with key CodingKeys - JSONDecoder error

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

My `Session` model looks like this

```
public struct Session: Codable {
    let name: String
    
    let key: String
    
    let subscriber: Int
}
```

I want to call the API with the Alamofire's `responseData` method and decode received data to the `Session` object, however the decoding fails everytime.

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post).responseData { response in
                    if let error = response.error {
                        failure?(error)
                    } else if let data = response.result.value {
                        do {
                            if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                                // This prints out a correct JSON string
                                print(str)
                            }
                            let session = try JSONDecoder().decode(Session.self, from: data)
                            success(session.key)
                        } catch let DecodingError.keyNotFound(key, context) {
                            print("Key '\(key)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
                            print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
                        } catch {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I'm printing the content of Data to the console before decoding and it looks like a valid JSON and I don't have any typos in my model whatsoever. What could be the reason why decoding is failing?

Output from the console:

> {"session":{"subscriber":0,"name":"someuser","key":"somekey"}}

> Key 'CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil)' not found: No
> value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue:
> nil) ("name"). codingPath: []

Comment: You are ignoring the root object, the dictionary with key `session`.

Comment: That's it, can't believe I didn't see it. Thanks